# Ruby Jekyll plug-in: undefined method '-@' for :flatify:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm getting the following error when attempting to build my Jekyll site:

```
jekyll 3.4.0 | Error: undefined method '-@' for :flatify:Symbol
```

I believe this is due to a plug-in I'm trying to use, as I can build when I remove the file from my plugins directory. The code for the plug-in is as follows:

```
---
---

module Jekyll
  module ExpandNestedVariableFilter
    def flatify(input)
      Liquid::Template.parse(input).render(@context)
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::ExpandNestedVariableFilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those `FrontMatter Dashes` at the beginning. The bug could be because Jekyll 'processes' all files with `---\n---\n`

Comment: My god, what a stupid error. Thank you for pointing this out! -_-